# Devise. Select role before registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise for user authentication on my Rails 4+ application.

Before user registration, user should select role, which should be assigned to user model. Depending on the selected role, will be rendered different signup forms.
So, basically I have 2 steps in my registration

1. Select role
2. Registration form

What will be the best approach to implement it. Thanks for sharing your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this. Hacky but easy way to do it would be to have all of the different form fields hidden and then reveal the correct ones based on the value in the select (using jquery). You could trigger via an on change event.